# Regex match a value only if the line does not begin with comment delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I think I need a regular expression that uses a look behind. I want the regular expression to match the 'this' in a string as long as it doesn't come after '//'

So for example it would match the 'this' if this was the string:

> I'm using this as my example

but not if it was:

> // I'm using this as my example

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Do you want to parse commented-out code?

Comment: //(?=this) would match the // that was followed by this
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @BartKiers (?!//) I've tried doing that before, but only works on what's directly next to it. I've never used lookbehinds before so sorry if that's completely wrong.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yeah that's the plan

Comment: @Joel I don't want to match the // I want to match the 'this' when it doesn't have // before it

Comment: (Psudocode) if(Regex.Match("this") && !Regex.Match(^//))   Maybe?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might find [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many situations where lookbehind seems like the obvious tool for the job, but you can't use it.  The main problem is that a lookbehind subexpression can't use quantifiers like `?`, `*`, `+`, or `{min,max}`, so this won't work:

```
preg_match('~(?<!//.*)\bthis\b~', $subject, $match);  // nope!
```

In most regex flavors you would have to match the whole line with a regex that doesn't allow `//` to appear anywhere before the token you're looking for.  @Gumbo showed one way to do that, and here's another:

```
preg_match('~^(?:(?!//).)*\bthis\b~', $subject, $match);
```

If your goal is to replace the token with another--for example, replacing `this` with `that`--you'll have to capture the stuff before it and plug it back in:

```
preg_replace('~^((?:(?!//).)*)\bthis\b~', '$1that', $subject);
```

However, PHP offers another option: `\K`, Match Point Reset operator (or as I like to call it, "Poor Man's Lookbehind").

```
preg_match('~^(?:(?!//).)*\K\bthis\b~', $subject, $match);
```

You match the preceding matter in the usual way, but the `\K` tells the regex engine to *pretend* the match really started just before the `\bthis\b`, not at the beginning of the string, so the value of `$match[0]` is simply `"this"`.  If you're doing a replace, there's no need to capture the preceding matter and plug it back in:

```
preg_replace('~^(?:(?!//).)*\K\bthis\b~', 'that', $subject);
```

`\K` originated in the Perl regex flavor.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression should do it:

```
^([^/]|/(?!/))*this
```

The `([^/]|/(?!/))*` matches any sequence that does not contain a `//`.